# How to Handle ARAnchor merge/replacement in the Unity ARKit Plugin

Tags: c#, objective-c, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to run an ARKit session in Unity (using the [Unity ARKit Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unity-arkit-plugin)), where the user selects a plane at the start of the session, and we build a world around that plane.

Obviously, ARKit's estimate of the plane updates as time goes on, and the application handles that through registering against the `UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARAnchorUpdatedEvent` and manipulates the game world accordingly; however when a plane is merged into another, I'm struggling to find a way to capture it so we can update with the new plane.

In ARCore, we are provided the "[subsumedBy](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Plane#merging)" field, when one plane is merged into another. We can then use this to trigger a change of planes by registering against an event:

```
public static Action<BoundedPlane,BoundedPlane> planeReplaced;

// ...

public override void Update()
{
    Session.GetTrackables<DetectedPlane>(m_DetectedPlaneBuffer, TrackableQueryFilter.All);
    foreach (var detectedPlane in m_DetectedPlaneBuffer)
    {
        // ...
        if (detectedPlane.SubsumedBy != null)
        {
            OnPlaneReplaced(boundedPlane, detectedPlane.SubsumedBy);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I assume the Unity plugin doesn't support this behaviour out of the box, so starting looking at the Objective-C native session implementation for clues. The closest I can see is the `[session:didUpdateAnchors][3]` delegate (and associated add/remove ones), but that doesn't seem to provide information on merges.

The worst case is that I can look for the most similar anchor in the event my chosen one is removed, but that seems hacky, so I wondered if there might be a better way.

Comment: ARCore now support iOS for some features. Actually, I'm working with Multi-AR Examples asset from Unity Assets store. My app use ARCore for the Anchor and floor managment in iPhone/iPad. Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

ARKit plug in has a removed anchor event.  Use that in conjunction with recently added anchors to find the closest anchor to the one removed:

```
void Start () {
    UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARAnchorAddedEvent += ARAnchorAdded;
    UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARAnchorRemovedEvent += ARAnchorRemoved;
}
void ARAnchorAdded(ARPlaneAnchor anchorData)
{
   //store anchorData in an array, you know the latest anchor is the newest.
}
void ARAnchorRemoved(ARPlaneAnchor anchorData)
{
   //find the closest anchor,  start at the bottom if you are looking for newest first
   //remove anchorData from the array 
}
```

Unity no longer supports the ARKit plug in, it is recommended to use the AR Foundation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@1.0/manual/index.html